# Non functioning Javascript in Custom Theme Layout in Communities

Tags: community

I've created own Custom Theme Layout for Community and inside this layout there are Javascript libraries. I included all the required libraries from static resource using  and they seem to load properly (I can see them in source) and there are no error in Chrome Console. However javascript funktionalities are still not available (like JS based language selector etc.).
It's very difficult to finde out what's going wrong. But maybe some have experience with Custom Theme Layouts with heavy JS usage?
Could it be some jQuery issue since two versions seems to be available - one in Lightning Component and one in general environment?
It also looks like Communities don't load Javascript libraries at once and not in proper order.

Comment: Is it possible to see somehow whether it's a Locker Issue or something different? Again no errors in console

Comment: the best way for you to determine that is by [understanding locker service](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/security_code.htm). If based on your comprehension the library you are using should work, feel free to update your post =)